# Primefaces 4.0: p:ajax partialSubmit inside compositeComponent

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, composite-component

I'm trying to create a simple composite component based on JSF h:panelGroup:
**filter.xhtml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <composite:interface>
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
        <span>Расширенный фильтр</span>
        <h:panelGroup id="#{cc.clientId}" class="filter"
            style="background:white">
            <composite:insertChildren></composite:insertChildren>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </composite:implementation>
```

and place a component that has to be partially submitted inside it.

```
 <h:form id="issueFilterForm" prependId="false">
        <c3:filter>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Продукт:" />
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{issueFilterBean.selectedProd}"
                    filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Выберите продукт" itemValue="-1" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{issueFilterBean.products}" var="proj"
                        itemLabel="#{proj.name}" itemValue="#{proj.id}" />
                    <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" update="@form"
                        partialSubmit="true" />

                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </c3:filter>
    </h:form>
```

The `p:ajax` call is fired, but no partial submission takes place. If i remove enclosing `c3:filter`, the submission works well.

How can I make this not skipping partial submission?

Comment: so it is doing a full submission?

Comment: No submission at all if processing `@this`. `process="@form"` works well.

Comment: Can you create an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve? So I can try to reproduce. And what jsf version did you use? And did you try a newer PF version?

Comment: I haven't tried newer version - the whole project needs to be rewrited if so.
I'll try.

Comment: You can maybe just try this case… no need for the whole project yet